# ALIGN_BOTTOM em relação à classe Pai

Tags: android, android-layout

Eu preciso que o menu fique ALIGN_BOTTOM em relação ao meu AppBar, mas o código abaixo não funciona.

```
public class AppBar extends RelativeLayout { 

 public AppBar(Context context) {

    RelativeLayout menu = new RelativeLayout(context);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM, this.getId());
    menu.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    this.addView(menu);

    this.setBackgroundResource(PKImageLoader.getResourceId(context,
            backgroundName));

}
```

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com a documentação do método [`addRule`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#addRule(int,%20int)). Usar o `ALIGN_BOTTOM` significa que quer alinhar uma `View` em relação ao fundo de uma outra `View` com o `id` especificado como `anchor`.

Porém, fazer essa regra com o `id` do `AppBar` (o pai) não surte efeito, porque provavelmente ele não acha o elemento e ignora, porque o `id` precisa ser de um outro filho do `RelativeLayout`.

Troque o `ALIGN_BOTTOM` pelo `ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM`, tire o segundo parâmetro e verifique o resultado.

```
public AppBar(Context context) {

    RelativeLayout menu = new RelativeLayout(context);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

    menu.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    this.addView(menu);

    this.setBackgroundResource(PKImageLoader.getResourceId(context, backgroundName));

}
```

Comment: já havia tentado isso, mas não funcionou.

Comment: @IgorRonner, de uma olhada no `Hierarchy Viewer`, no `DDMS` ou direto do sdk, se o `AppBar` está com tamanho suficiente para ele alinhar o `menu` para o fundo.